# I can't get an ES6 promise to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I can't grasp how promises work. So I figured I'd just jump in and try and create one to see if that helps.  But the following returns an undefined value (arrTables):

```
app.get("/getTables", function (req, res) {
    var arrTables = getTables().then(function(response) {
        console.log("getTables() resolved");
        console.log(arrTables.length);
        console.log(arrTables[1].ID());
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("getTables() finished with an error");
    });
});

function getTables() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        while (mLobby.tlbCount() < LOBBY_SIZE) {
            var objTable = new Table();
            mLobby.addTable(objTable);
        }
        resolve(mLobby.tables);
    });
}
```

`new Table()` references a custom class that makes an async database call.  I'm trying to use promises to make sure that call resolves before I continue in the code.  Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Here's the console output:

```
getTables() resolved
undefined
(node:6580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id:
 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined
```

Edit to add: mLobby.tblCount starts out as 0, so it does enter the while loop.

Comment: You need to wait for the database call to complete before you resolve. How exactly you do that depends on what mechanism `Table` provides for knowing when it's done.

Comment: arrTables.length ? is that not suppose to be response.length? since thats what you called for the callback?

Comment: @skirtle The table class returns from inside a callback function on finishing its database queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the array variable. the GetTable method returns nothing and output of this method is stored in response variable not in `arrTables` variable. try to use `response` variable instead of `arrTables`

```
 getTables().then(function(response) {
    var arrTables = response //Added
    console.log("getTables() resolved");
    console.log(arrTables.length);
    console.log(arrTables[1].ID);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("getTables() finished with an error");
});
```

Comment: Or just `getTables().then(function (arrTables) { ...`

Comment: this gives the following console output:


getTables() resolved
3
(node:5580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id:
 1): TypeError: arrTables[1].ID is not a function


Class Table ID method is:


ID() {
        console.log("inside table class ID function.  this.ID: " + this.ID);
        return this.ID;
    }
I don't know how to do block code format in comments. Can someone edit it?

Comment: @erv Updated ans

Comment: Removing the `()` after `arrTables[1].ID()` returns a blank line on the console.  And some logging messages in the `.ID()` method of `class Table` don't output at all.  As far as I am aware you need the brackets for calling your own custom class methods.

Comment: changing the `ID()` method of `class Table` to `somethingID()` has resolved that problem.  `ID()` must be a reserved inbuilt method or something.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting to the control flow of Promises can take some getting used to. 
You're close! But...

`var arrTables = getTables().then(function(response) {
 console.log("getTables() resolved");
 console.log(arrTables.length); ...`
is a variable declaration.

This is analogous to writing `var a = a`.  You cannot access arrTables in the declaration of arrTables because it hasn't been declared yet!

The anonymous function you are passing to `.then()` (where you erroneously try to access properties of the the, at the time, `undefined` variable arrTables) is the very same function that you call as `resolve(mLobby.tables)` within your promise.

The promise you return from `getTables` ***promises*** to pass `mLobby.tables()` to your anonymous function as `response`.

I recommend doing some practice with promises before trying to work them into a larger application.

The excellent nodeschool.io workshopper [promise-it-wont-hurt](https://github.com/stevekane/promise-it-wont-hurt) was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code.

```
app.get("/getTables", async function (req, res) {
    var arrTables = await getTables()
    console.log(arrTables.length);
     console.log(arrTables[1].ID());
});

async function getTables() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            while (mLobby.tlbCount() < LOBBY_SIZE) {
                var objTable = new Table();
                mLobby.addTable(objTable);
            }
            resolve(mLobby.tables);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error("getTables() finished with an error");
            reject(err)
        }
    });
}
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: Throws this error:

app.get("/getTables", async function (req, res) {
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list